# Help with exercise: On a smooth curve there is a moving mass point

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, physics, classical-mechanics

We have a mass point moving on a smooth curve: $$r = a\cos(\phi/2) (\sin(\phi) i + \cos(\phi) j), a>0$$

On this mass point there is gravity force.

We need to calculate the stable position.

Professor's solution:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Can somebody please explain how did we get $U$. I do not understand this solution.

Comment: the potential energy for the uniform force field given by gravity is $U=mgy$ where $y$ is the vertical coordinate (I assume, the direction of what you call $j$)

Comment: @GiulioR Yes, but isnt gravity force = $mg(\cos(phi)i + \sin(phi)j)$, and we would have to multiply it with $r$  ??

Comment: @GiulioR Then we would get $ U =mg (\cos(\phi)\sin(\phi) i + sin(\phi)cos(phi) j)a\cos(\phi/2)$, but that is not what the professor's solution says

Comment: no, the gravity force is just $mg$ directed downwards